# IE8 animated banner ad - Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, performance, internet-explorer-8, adobe-edge

I've created a HTML5 banner ad (using Adobe Edge) for at client of mine. The client now wants the banner to work with IE8. A static banner fallback solution is not an option for the client. I've tried to tell the client that the cost vs. benefit in this situation is horrible, but unfortunately it doesn't matter. The clients wants IE8 support. Sigh! :(

My first approach in solving this issue was to use jQuery animate, but I'm worried that IE8 wont render multiple animations very good?

Anyone in here have a suggestion for at solution, or have practical experience in accomplishing this? Is it even possible to create an acceptable animated banner with IE8 (no flash)?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What do you mean by "animated"? Perhaps you could use a _GIF_

Comment: Have you mentioned that the major source of IE8 is no longer supported.. e.g. windows XP? At this point home users should be on IE11 if they are using windows 7, only corporate users should be stuck on IE8.

Comment: @Mgetz _Windows 7 RTM_ shipped with _IE8_ :/ Though yes, it was the last _IE_ compatible with XP.

Comment: @PaulS. I'm aware, which is why I said corporate users should be the only ones stuck on IE8. Everybody else will have IE11 pushed quite aggressively to them.

Comment: By animation I mean fadeIn/fadeOut, rotation, movement of elements horizontal/vertical. Stuff like that :)